# passing a type argument for the props of a react component for a higher order component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a created a [playground of the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=1&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=49&pc=81#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwOoEtgAsDCX0A2AJnBAHYA8MAfFALyxQBkUA3lAMb7GlkD8ALigBDMiCgBfANwAoGejLAIcAGbCO0AGI4q9NhNqsZUE1AAUYRCiHwkaTLm4lyVagBpOCRRAAewQSJiAJRCoiCyEnKgkFAAQsLIEJroEMTIekYmBMIARqlCyMBwCgDmEbIyvmAIcMBQ0dA4CAC21WTkwLYoACrgEBQ4tAw4UL5KZETp2hQKKsqwtHyMQjgVVTV1KgCuZBzA6F5QvETKmjXNTYqIBAAiEIVwW3tbpES6Y+STsFb22HiEzko8USyVSk2o1DMTVaQmmNCCbGMnjIhSgqDgwjAkCIsJ0ND0ZnY2TyBA8ADoKaRURIEXRDEiTKRgC8yFABi0wFBiak6KxuQQJGwKWSqcBBQB6aiyEzSORIpkstEYrEQIgROXrWpQba7faHY6nc6XIoIAgAOQQwDuDyezNe7z8n3SXV+jgBvAowKSKTSEKhHNxrgRmWRqPRmOxgfxDAsP1p9NMRwgdtZ7NaQopljsgv5vKzKDJ-IlUqRsrkjOTivDKrVMkiMgaUAAyqkIHsXRQAPJgPVkXqQIaIxNIXvIITd3v9iAAbQAuhFmHEEt6wcgKhwvKiWwQ28BA9vdx2dgBrMgIADuZAhBNYI4OKJp9ATpg3KNNEELCBKZjvm6CdbkV9UTOOBmgPPYAEY9ANOAQIuLwTVue4iltF5VTMcDgCCddNzqODMIAJmgz5DVA41rgtK1kMeZ5Xgw1s9mwwDN3fT9v3whjgAgjwOJ3PYCKCIA)

and here is the code:

```js
type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: any };

interface FC<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): any;
}

type BaseFields = {
  label: string;
};

export type ComponentPropsType<C> = C extends FC<infer P> ? P : C;

export function renderFormControlDestructured<P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>>(Comp: FC<P>) {
  const Wrapped: FC<P> = ({ label, ...rest }) => {
    return <Comp label={label} {...rest} />;
  };


  return Wrapped;
}


export function renderFormControlNotDestructured<P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>>(Comp: FC<P>) {
  const Wrapped: FC<P> = (props) => {
    return <Comp {...props} label={props.label} />;
  };


  return Wrapped;
}

type SelectProps<OptionType> = {
    options: OptionType[];
} & BaseFields;

const Select: FC<SelectProps<unknown>> = ({options}) => {
    console.log(options)
}

const FormSelect1 = renderFormControlDestructured(Select);

const FormSelect2 = renderFormControlNotDestructured(Select);

console.log(FormSelect1, FormSelect2)
```

I want typescript to infer the Props from the component that is passed but I get the following error message

The long and the short of it is if I destructure my arguments for a higher-order component like this

```js
export function renderFormControlDestructured<P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>>(Comp: FC<P>) {
  const Wrapped: FC<P> = ({ label, ...rest }) => {
    return <Comp label={label} {...rest} />;
  };


  return Wrapped;
}
```

I get the error message:

```
Type '{ label: string; } & Pick<PropsWithChildren<P>, "children" | Exclude<keyof P, "label">>' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<P>'.
Type '{ label: string; } & Pick<PropsWithChildren<P>, "children" | Exclude<keyof P, "label">>' is not assignable to type 'P'.
'{ label: string; } & Pick<PropsWithChildren<P>, "children" | Exclude<keyof P, "label">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>'.
```

But if I don't restructure, I don't get the error

```js
export function renderFormControlNotDestructured<P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>>(Comp: FC<P>) {
  const Wrapped: FC<P> = (props) => {
    return <Comp {...props} label={props.label} />;
  };


  return Wrapped;
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler allows one and not the other of what is effectively the same thing.

Comment: It looks like the compiler is having trouble reconciling the destructured types even though they are logically the same. The alternate solution without destructuring will get you the outcome that you need. I suggest sticking with that solution.

Comment: Can you give us some feedback please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with destructuring `PropsWithChildren<P>`.

```
export function renderFormControlDestructured<P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>>(Comp: FC<P>) {
  const Wrapped: FC<P> = ({ label, ...rest }) => {
    return <Comp label={label} {...rest} />;
  };

  return Wrapped;
}
```

Here `rest` is of type `Pick<PropsWithChildren<P>, "children" | Exclude<keyof P, "label">>` which is a type different from `PropsWithChildren<P>`.

We know that type `{ label: string; } & Pick<PropsWithChildren<P>, "children" | Exclude<keyof P, "label">>` is equivalent to `PropsWithChildren<P>` but they are clearly two distinct types.

If we expand the `FC` interface in `renderFormControlDestructured` declaration we have:

```
export function renderFormControlDestructured<P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>>(Comp: (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): any) {
  const Wrapped: (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): any = ({ label, ...rest }) => {
    return <Comp label={label} {...rest} />;
  };

  return Wrapped;
}
```

so `props` is of type `PropsWithChildren<P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>>`, indeed  if we change the declaration removing one nested `PropsWithChildren` from the type of `props`:

```
function renderFormControlDestructured<P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>>(Comp: FC<BaseFields>)
```

the error disappear.

Nesting multiple times `PropsWithChildren` actually doesn't change the type, the first time it adds the optional `children` property, the next times replace the property with the same property (actually a noop); but it seems that the multiple nested templates makes hard to TypeScript rebuilding the type back.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [limitation of TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35858) and it's not related to destructuring. This code will produce the same error without any destructuring:

```
export function renderFormControlDestructured<
  P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>
>(Comp: ComponentType<P>) {
  // error in the next line
  const p: P = {
    label: "my label",
    children: "my children",
  };
}
```

Usually, you will be using HOC to add something to the passed component. This is an example of that which will produce the same error:

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren, ComponentType } from "react";

type BaseFields = {
  label: string;
  anotherProp: boolean;
};

export function renderFormControlDestructured<
  P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>
>(Comp: ComponentType<P>) {
  const Wrapped = (props: Omit<P, "anotherProp">) => {
    // error
    const newProps: P = {
      ...props,
      anotherProp: true,
    };
    return <Comp {...newProps} />;
  };

  return Wrapped;
}
```

A simple fix for that is using type assertion:

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren, ComponentType } from "react";

type BaseFields = {
  label: string;
  anotherProp: boolean;
};

export function renderFormControlDestructured<
  P extends PropsWithChildren<BaseFields>
>(Comp: ComponentType<P>) {
  const Wrapped = (props: Omit<P, "anotherProp">) => {
    // no error
    const newProps: P = {
      ...props,
      anotherProp: true,
    } as P;
    return <Comp {...newProps} />;
  };

  return Wrapped;
}
```